# Padding inside LI element

Tags: html, css, padding

I cannot get the padding property to work inside my `<li>` tag.

**This is my CSS:**

```
.menu li{
   height:50px;
   display: inline;
   padding:10px 15px 18px 15px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 0px 2px;
   -moz-border-image: url(../img/menuborder.png) 0 2 stretch repeat;
   -webkit-border-image: url(../img/menuborder.png) 0 2 stretch repeat;
   -o-border-image: url(../img/menuborder.png) 0 2 stretch repeat;
   border-image: url(../img/menuborder.png) 0 2 stretch repeat;
   border-right:0;
}

.menu a{
   color:#fff;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding-top:10px;
}
```

**Here is my .HTML:**

```
   <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Incentives</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Yet, the padding-top doesn't seem to affect the text inside the a and li tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably need to apply the padding to the `a` element. And you will need to make that a block-level element for the top/bottom padding to work:

```
.menu a { 
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 15px 18px 15px;
}
```

Note: `inline-block` is only partially supported in IE7 and below. You can use `display: block;` and `float:left` if the above does not work as expected.

Also important to mention that the base issue here is the `display:inline` on your `li`s in the CSS, and the fact that the `a` tag is `inline` by default. You cannot apply top/bottom padding to an `inline` element.

Comment: why to the anchor tag instead of the `li` element?

Comment: @Head, mostly b/c I do it that way and know it works w/o testing. but also because it increases the 'clickable area' for each menu link.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Placing the padding on the anchor makes more sense in this case as it seems this is a navigation menu which can benefit from the larger area available to click on.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Sounds like a good enough reason to me. I'd encourage you to add explanations for why you make even the smallest changes - it is what makes a good answer. A note on IE > 7 support - you can add `*display:inline; *zoom: 1` to reproduce the `inline-block` behavour

Answer (score 5):

padding won't work for

```
display: inline;
```

try

```
display: block;
```

instead, and optionally

```
float: left;
```

Comment: inline-block is an option as well. just need to remember, between inline-blocked element will be small gap if tags in html will be separated with anything (char, space, even newline). to avoid it, you need to set font-size: 0; to container, and then of course font-size for inline-blocked elements

Answer (score 1):

You could also try setting `line-height` for the `a` to match the height of the `li` like so:

```
.menu a{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/9TcRP/

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu li a{color:#fff;text-decoration: none;padding-top:10px;}
```

This will add padding to the list items themselves. You will need to give styling to the

```
.menu
```

itself in order to add all the other padding (left right) to the block of list items.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to give you li a class name and try your styling for that class.

Answer (score 0):

You want the top padding on the menu itself.  Not the anchor or list element.

```
.menu {padding-top: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

**CSS**

```
.menu li{
  padding:7px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>first element
    <li>second element
    <li>third element
    <li>fourth element
  </ul>
</div>
```