# Replace font in Asp.net MVC Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Firstly I am new in Asp.net MVC. How to add new font-face in ASP.NET MVC project. In my project contains **Arial font**, but I want to add **Futura LT** and I had tried this style but font not replaced by **Futura LT** it remains the same.
I have .ttf file and I had added to my font folder. is that any other method for include font in the **Asp.net MVC** project. Thanks in Advance !!!

```
<style>
 @@font-face { 
font-family: Futura_LT_Book ; 
src: url('/fonts/Futura_LT_Book.ttf') format("truetype");
 } 
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain properly. What type of design do you want for listing?

Comment: Check this answer out. [Padding inside li element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019738/9168603)

Comment: Please provide us with more specific information about your question.

Comment: Please give an example of what you _want_ your code to look like.

Comment: I will display Images

Comment: The snippet doesn't demonstrate the problem, so I'm not sure what kind of answer to give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .ttl file to your asp.net project > font folder. then easily you can get new style.
And you can see this

> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389557/how-to-add-custom-font-in-asp-net-mvc-5)

for more reference.

Comment: Only add this .ttl file of my new style then automatically added to my font family.

Comment: No, you should restart your project.

Comment: Yes Its run properly and I get my fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to ul tag instead of li tag that' s it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add class and apply font-family to this class. Source code is below

```
<style>
 @@font-face { 
font-family: Futura_LT_Book ; 
src: url('/fonts/Futura_LT_Book.ttf') format("truetype");
 } 

.classname{
font-family:Futura_LT_Book
}
</style>
```